# Detect outliers in multi dimensions

Tags: outliers, multidimensional-scaling, high-dimensional

I tried to implement outlier detection for one dimension using inter quartile.
For instance, a given variable cost or revenue or profit. but I'm missing outliers in other dimensions when running for one dimension.

How to detect outliers for multi dimensional data , like cost and revenue and profit at once.

Is there any efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: It depends on your purposes. You can take a look at Mahalanobis distance if your data is normal.

Comment: Unfortunately data isn't normally distributed

Comment: Then you can use combined p-values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method , but it will work only if you have independent coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Python, you could try [SVM One Class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html) and Least Squares Anomaly Detection, both are unsupervised learning, so you train giving "examples" of inliers.